# Getting error "Unknown column 'text' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to insert text to my database table `reqviews`. But I get the error message:

`Unknown column 'text' in 'field list'`. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Please help

```
if (isset($_POST['combut'])) {
    $rqvcom = $_POST['rqvcom'];
    $rqid = (int)$_GET['rqid'];
    $conn->query("
        INSERT INTO reqviews (rqvrqid, rqvuserid, rqvcom, rqvdate)
            SELECT {$rqid}, {$sid}, {$rqvcom}, NOW()
            FROM requests
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT rqid
                FROM requests
                WHERE rqid = {$rqid})
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT rqvid
                FROM reqviews
                WHERE rqvuserid = {$sid}
                AND rqvrqid = {$rqid})
            LIMIT 1
    ");
}
```

What my code does: When some text is typed into `rqvcom` textarea, that text gets iserted to `rqvcom` column on `reqviews` table. If a row already exists on `reqviews` table with a `rqvuserid` user, then another row with that same userid cannot be inserted. My problem is my code gives me the error message I provided.

Edit: Table `reqviews`

```
rqvid | rqvrqid | rqvuserid | rqvcom | rqvdate
```

Table `requests`

```
rqid
```

Comment: `text` is the exact column name you get? try to execute the same query with plain values instead of using PHP placeholders

Comment: @GiacomoM No, 'text' is literally the word I typed into my textarea field. The textarea field has an attribute of `name="rqvcom"`. I was really confused myself why the error message would even call 'text' a column. Which made absolutely no sense at all to me.

Comment: If "text" is the value of `$rqvcom` this line `SELECT {$rqid}, {$sid}, {$rqvcom}, NOW()` will try to select the column `text`

Comment: Since you are inserting strings, you have to escape them in the `SELECT` statement. Be careful of Sql Injections

Comment: @kerbholz And the confusing thing is, I have no such column named 'text' on my database. I don't know how to resolve this issue

Comment: That's why you get the error. What are you trying to select using `$rqvcom`?

Comment: @GiacomoM Sorry, but my question has nothing to do with escaping strings nor asking about sql injections. I am able to insert this statement into my database using another select method, but I need to use this one. And I'm wondering how I can get this to work. I know there is a way.

Comment: are you sure has nothing to do? :D you are inserting string, so you have to use something like this: ... `SELECT 'text', 'your value',` ecc... if you do not use the `'` character mysql thinks that `text` is the name of the column. That's why you get that error

Comment: @kerbholz I am trying to select `rqvid`, which is the primary key for the table `reqviews`, and which I assume selects the entire row, including `rqvcom`.

Comment: @GiacomoM So you're saying I should wrap each of these `{$rqid}, {$sid}, {$rqvcom}, NOW()` in single quotes? Since these are the columns I am trying to select?

Comment: @misner3456 yes. But if you do that without any other update, you are vulnerable to Sql injections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to insert the value of `$rqvcom` into the database, you need to put it in quotes, since it's a string. Otherwise, it's treated as a column name.

```
$conn->query("
    INSERT INTO reqviews (rqvrqid, rqvuserid, rqvcom, rqvdate)
        SELECT {$rqid}, {$sid}, '{$rqvcom}', NOW()
        FROM requests
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT rqid
            FROM requests
            WHERE rqid = {$rqid})
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT rqvid
            FROM reqviews
            WHERE rqvuserid = {$sid}
            AND rqvrqid = {$rqid})
        LIMIT 1
");
```

However, this leaves you open to SQL injection, so you should use a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO reqviews (rqvrqid, rqvuserid, rqvcom, rqvdate)
        SELECT ?, ?, ?, NOW()
        FROM requests
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT rqid
            FROM requests
            WHERE rqid = ?)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT rqvid
            FROM reqviews
            WHERE rqvuserid = ?
            AND rqvrqid = ?)
        LIMIT 1
");
$stmt->bind_param("iisiii", $rqid, $sid, $rqvcom, $rqid, $sid, $rqid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Yes - this resolved everything! Wow - you never fail to provide the exact solution to an answer and incorporate more than is asked, seriously thank you! I was trying to figure out at the same time how to make this into a prepared statement but wasn't sure how. Thankfully, you were able to do this, and I see what Giacomo meant when he said to wrap rqvcom in quotes now. Really, I cannot appreciate your help enough, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT {$rqid}, {$sid}, {$rqvcom}, NOW()
```

This will select the column names that are in those variables:

```
// let's say these are the values in your variables:
$rqid = "text";
$sid = "session123";
$rqvcom = "example";

// then this query:
SELECT {$rqid}, {$sid}, {$rqvcom}, NOW()

// is the same as:
SELECT text, session123, example, NOW()
```

That is why you're getting that error. It is highly unlikely that this is what you want. I suspect that what you *actually* want is to select the columns `rqid`, `sid` and `rqvcom`:

```
SELECT rqid, sid, rqvcom, NOW()
```

**Edit**: Now that you've added your table structures, it seems more likely that you want to actually select the string values, in which case you need to wrap the variables in quotes like @Giacomo M suggested:

```
SELECT '{$rqid}', '{$sid}', '{$rqvcom}', NOW()

// which will become:
SELECT 'text', 'session123', 'example', NOW()
```

Then your database will not confuse the strings with column names.

Comment: But these are my table column names - `(rqvrqid, rqvuserid, rqvcom, rqvdate)` as defined within the `insert` line. Luckily your method using this worked: `SELECT '{$rqid}', '{$sid}', '{$rqvcom}', NOW()`, and this allowed me to insert the variables to my table. But I'm left with a strange error that it inserts 6 rows total when it should only insert 1?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `LIMIT 1` will be interpreted as part of the SELECT or as part of the INSERT statement. So, if you execute only the SELECT portion of the query, how many rows does it return? And is it possible this code is executed multiple times? Either way, that's a different problem and should maybe be a separate question (you can link to this one if you like).

Comment: @rickdenhaan It will be part of the SELECT statement. INSERT doesn't have a LIMIT clause.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I got the 6 row insert resolved using Barmar's code. But I also upvoted yours since this also helped with my issue - thanks!